# How to do web scraping using htmlunitsriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, htmlunit-driver

i am getting somthing like this [image]
Hi i am scraping a web page using Selenium Webdriver an i am able to achieve my data but problem is that this directly interact with browser  and i dont want to open a web browser and  want to scrape all data as it is

How can i achieve my goal

Here is my code

```
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
    
    public class GetData {
    
        public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
            String sDate = "27/03/2014";
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            String url="http://www.upmandiparishad.in/commodityWiseAll.aspx";
            driver.get(url);
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            // select barge
            new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddl_commodity"))).selectByVisibleText("Jo");
             driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txt_rate")).sendKeys(sDate);
            // click buttonctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txt_rate
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btn_show")).click();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
    
            //get only table tex
            WebElement findElement = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1"));
            String htmlTableText = findElement.getText();
            // do whatever you want now, This is raw table values.
        System.out.println(htmlTableText);
           
     
            driver.close();
            driver.quit();
    
        }
    }


My updated New code



import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

    public class Getdata1 {
    
        public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
            WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6);
        driver.get("http://www.upmandiparishad.in/commodityWiseAll.aspx");
        System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        // select barge         
        new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddl_commodity"))).selectByVisibleText("Jo");
    
        String sDate = "12/04/2014"; //What date you want
        driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txt_rate")).sendKeys(sDate);
    
        driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btn_show")).click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    
        //get only table tex
        WebElement findElement = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1"));
        String htmlTableText = findElement.getText();
        // do whatever you want now, This is raw table values.
        System.out.println(htmlTableText);
    
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
    
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Change firefox version to a latest one.Or change it chrome.. That should me the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use HtmlUnit or HtmlUnitDriver by Selenium

```
    WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_17);
    driver.get("http://www.upmandiparishad.in/commodityWiseAll.aspx");
    System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    // select barge         
    new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddl_commodity"))).selectByVisibleText("Jo");

    String sDate = "12/04/2014"; //What date you want
    driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txt_rate")).sendKeys(sDate);

    driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btn_show")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    //get only table tex
    WebElement findElement = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1"));
    String htmlTableText = findElement.getText();
    // do whatever you want now, This is raw table values.
    System.out.println(htmlTableText);

    driver.close();
    driver.quit();
```

To get tabular output, you can try something like this..

```
    String arrCells[] = htmlTableText.split(" ");
    Boolean bIsANumber = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < arrCells.length; i++) {

        try {
            int tmp = Integer.parseInt(arrCells[i]);
            bIsANumber = true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            bIsANumber = false;
        }

        if(bIsANumber) {
            System.out.print("\n"+arrCells[i]+"\t");
        }
        else {
            System.out.print(arrCells[i]+"\t");
        }
    }
```

Comment: how can i change in chrome

Comment: `WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.CHROME);` Doc : http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/HtmlUnitDriver

Comment: i will have any extra jar file for chrome?

Comment: No, it is inside HtmlUnitDriver. Download latest firefox and try HtmlUnitDriver with new latest firefox version.

Comment: chrome is not adding  here

Comment: dear i have installed latest version of firfox still not working

Comment: Did you change `HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_17); BrowserVersion`?

Comment: i  install  17 and made change

Comment: May be there should have something newer than FIREFOX_3_6. Put that one and try..

Comment: can u tell me which jar file should i use for htmlunitdriver

Comment: Are you using any IDE? If yes, what is it?

Comment: i am using netbeans ide

Comment: i am getting something like my posted image

Comment: data is displaying like "S.No.DistrictMarketPrice 1 Agra Achhnera NIL 2 Agra Agra NIL 3 Agra Fatehabad NIL 4 Agra Fatehpur Sikri NIL"  and  i want it should be in tabuler form as it was coiming before

Comment: How i will get exact data

Comment: Great, yes that is why I said result will be bit different than early one. Now it's just for loop case.. You can do it easily...

Comment: Thanks dear without u  it was not possible  u made my day

Comment: It's my pleasure to help you.. :)

Comment: could i have email id

Comment: or facebook id if u dont have any prob

Comment: I'm not sure whether this site allow to share those kind of details. We may get banned..

Comment: u can update ur id  in ur profile i u want or u can take my from there

Comment: Thanks dear for  sharing ur id